# AutoLayout In Side UI Element

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm pretty new to Auto Layout, I want to group an UIImage with a UILabel, so that UILabel would be centered to UIImage whenever UIImage changes. Right now my UILabel is constrained to the edges of device. Any suggestions highly appreciated.

[image: Image in Storyboard]

Comment: Constrain the center of the label to the center of image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select both views and then use the "Align" button on the bottom of the Interface Builder. There check horizontal centers and/or vertical centers.
[image: Interface Builder]